# How to split a stream of Strings and generate a List of String-arrays?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, incompatibletypeerror

I am fairly new to streams, so please help me out (and be gentle).

What I would like to do is the following. I have a `BufferedReader` that reads from a file in which each line looks something like this: "a, b". For example:

*Example Input file*

"a, b"

"d, e"

"f, g"

I would like to convert this to a `LinkedList<String[]>`:

*Example `LinkedList<String[]>`*

[{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"f", "g"}]

How would you do this using a stream approach?

This is what I tried:

```
List numbers = reader.lines().map(s -> s.split("[\\W]")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This does not work. My IDE provides the following feedback:

```
Incompatible types. Required List but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to List
```

It shows... I am still trying to figure streams out.

Comment: Start by not using raw types. What should the List contains? If you didn't use rwa types, your code would be typesafe, and we would have that critical information. Also, why would you use a LinkedList? In 99;99% of the cases, an ArrayList is a better choice than a LinkedList.

Comment: @JBNizet: Do you mean use `LinkedList<String> numbers = ...` instead of `List numbers = ...`? I have tried that as well, didn't make a difference.

Comment: `[{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"f", "g"}]`

what is the type of `{"a", "b"}`? `Map<String, String>`? `Map.Entry<String, String>`?

Comment: No. I mean just List<String> instead of the raw List. So you want a list of Strings? What should each String of the list contain? Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest avoiding the use of raw types and instead, use `List<String[]>` as the receiver type.

```
List<String[]> numbers = reader.lines()
                               .map(s -> s.split(delimiter)) // substitute with your deilimeter
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You mentioned that you wanted a `LinkedList` implementation. you should almost always  favour `ArrayList` which `toList` returns by default *currently* although it is not guaranteed to persist thus, you can specify the list implementation explcitly with `toCollection`:

```
List<String[]> numbers = reader.lines()
                               .map(s -> s.split(delimiter)) // substitute with your deilimeter
                               .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

and likewise for `LinkedList`:

```
List<String[]> numbers = reader.lines()
                               .map(s -> s.split(delimiter)) // substitute with your deilimeter
                               .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You may do it like so,

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources", "data.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    List<String> strings = lines.flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(","))).map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
}
```

Read each line of the file, then split it using the delimiter. After that trim it to eliminate any remaining white space characters. Finally collect it to a result container.

Comment: Would prefer this over the current answer IMHO. (+1)

Comment: @nullpointer But this code yields a `List<String>` instead of a `List<String[]>`...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that's the reason actually I would prefer this. Maybe I just find it difficult to see List of an array as one.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that each line is a tuple of 2 elements you could collect them into a List of something that looks like a tuple of 2 elements.
Note that Java doesn't have native type for tuples (like Scala  or python), so you should choose a way to represent the elements.

you could create a list of entry :

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> numbers = 
                 reader.lines()
                       .map(s -> s.split(","))
                       .map(a -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a[0], a[1]))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or a list of String :

```
List<String> numbers = reader.lines()
                             .map(s -> s.split(","))
                             .map(a -> "{" + a[0] + "," + a[1] + "}"))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that generally, you don't want to stick to a specific list implementation as you collect the stream while in some cases you can need. In this case, specify the collection supplier to use with
`toCollection(LinkedList::new)` instead of `toList()`

Comment: The first approach is another nice way to store two related items +1. Although, the second approach would be difficult to deal with you if you later want to access each individual item and do something with it.

Comment: Agreed for the second. It sounds more usable as a data format. Not easy to answer smartly with a broad requirement :) EDIT : oh it was in the title   "and generate a List of String-arrays?" My bad :)